# Illegal parameter number in definition of \captionsspanish

Tags: errors, lyx

I installed Lyx 2.3.7 on Windows. It seems to work well, except I found this problem when rendering the built-in User Guide into pdf using Ctrl-R:

[image]

It seems this line is the cause of all errors:

[image]

Latex code:

```
\selectlanguage{spanish}%
\begin{itemize}
\selectlanguage{spanish}%
\item En una frase \nobreakdash\textemdash un inciso con rayas\textemdash{}
se escribe así.
\end{itemize}
```

Just deleting the line removes all errors. I cannot pinpoint the faulty portion. I wonder whether this is a local install issue or whether the document actually contains an error. If so which one?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I don't get the error. Also tried on windows. Maybe you need to update your packages or LaTeX distribution?

Comment: @UdiFogiel: Thanks. I did not use the full install of TextLive (this was not recommended in the instructions) and perhaps I miss some packages, but I don't know which ones, Lyx doesn't complain about one missing and renders the file after the line is deleted...

Comment: I would actually recommend to install TeXLive full, as it is not that heavy compared to the space computers have nowadays. If you don't want to reinstall tex live just install the missing packages from TeXLive's package manager GUI. Maybe you should check first for updates for you already installed packages (probably related to babel).

Comment: @UdiFogiel: I added the whole list of uninstalled packages to the existing installation. This solved the problem. Your intuition was good! Thanks. I remember I unchecked several languages during the initial installation of Tex, thinking it was related to the UI and the spell checker, perhaps it had deeper implications for babel. If you feel like writing an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the authors last comment and answer say „solution found, problem solved“.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating packages and installing missing ones (see the comments).